# Averaging specific values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
PHP Syntax (Toggle Plain Text)
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          1 => string '00:00' (length=5)
          2 => string '34.83' (length=5)
          3 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          4 => string '00:00' (length=5)
          5 => string '34.83' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array
          0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          1 => string '01:00' (length=5)
          2 => string '32.07' (length=5)
          3 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          4 => string '01:00' (length=5)
          5 => string '32.07' (length=5)
      2 => 
        array
          0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          1 => string '02:00' (length=5)
          2 => string '28.69' (length=5)
          3 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          4 => string '02:00' (length=5)
          5 => string '28.69' (length=5)
      3 => 
        array
          0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          1 => string '03:00' (length=5)
          2 => string '28.17' (length=5)
          3 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          4 => string '03:00' (length=5)
          5 => string '28.17' (length=5)
```

### **What I'm trying to do is average each 2/5 element with eachother into > a new array with the Date/Time. so have something like**

```
array
0 => 
array
0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
1 => string '00:00' (length=5)
2 => string 'AVERAGE OF 2&5' (length=5)
PHP Syntax (Toggle Plain Text)
      1 => 
        array
          0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          1 => string '01:00' (length=5)
          2 => string 'AVERAGE OF 2&5' (length=5)
      2 => 
        array
          0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          1 => string '02:00' (length=5)
          2 => string 'AVERAGE OF 2&5' (length=5)
      3 => 
        array
          0 => string '12/08/2011' (length=10)
          1 => string '03:00' (length=5)
          2 => string 'AVERAGE OF 2&5' (length=5)
```

Any help would be appreciated, i've been trying ot figure this out for a couple of hours now and can't wrap my head around achieving this? ... Do i need to explode the elements to their own array, average then reinsert?

thank you.

Comment: Explode what? Those look to be numbers already, so there should be no need to do any further exploding.

Comment: Sorry i had the Titel wrong-I'm looking to Average each 2/5 value   of the original array and insert that value to the corresponding key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer rdlowrey's methods, but this is likely easier to understand for most people.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $subArray) {
    $ave = ($subArray[2] + $subArray[5]) / 2;
    $arr[$key] = array($subArray[0], $subArray[1], $ave);
}
```

Comment: what if the array is is 132 values, and i need value 2,5 and then every 5th after that .. so 7/10 12/15 17/20  and so on up to 132

Comment: What did you try? Read the code, and try to understand it. THe modification needed should be quite clear to you.

Comment: I tried to do a for loop around it with $i=2;$i<132;i+=5  and one for n=5 " " ..  Which then gave me undefined offset in five before i even did anything.     .. otherwise I'd do one giant query with a + $subArray[2] +""[5] +""[7]+""[10] and so on?

Answer (score 2):

If you have php5.3+ you can do this in two lines (and one if you like difficult to read function calls) using a closure with array_map:

```
$f = function($x) { return array($x[0], $x[1], ($x[2]+$x[5])/2); };
$new = array_map($f, $arr);
print_r($new);
```

The closure returns a new array with the two values you requested and averages the values of keys 2 and 5.

---

If you don't have PHP5.3, use a regular function:

```
function dan_is_awesome($x) { return array($x[0], $x[1], ($x[2]+$x[5])/2); };
$new = array_map('dan_is_awesome', $arr);
print_r($new);
```

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) takes as its first argument a callback function that it then performs on each element of the input array.

---

**UPDATE**

Stack Overflow **IS NOT** a substitute for logical thinking. *"Can you do this for me"* is not a legitimate question. However ...

If you needed to accomodate the requirements listed in the comment below (averaging keys 2/5/7/10/12/15 ... and so on to the end of the array) you could do:

```
function dan_is_awesome($x)
{
  $avg_vals = array($x[2], $x[5]);

  $i = 10;
  while ($i < count($x)) {
    if ($i % 10 == 0     // divisible by 10
      || $i-5 % 10 == 0  // divisible by 5
      || $i % 2 == 0     // divisible by 2
    ) { 
      $avg_vals[] = $x[$i];
    }
    ++$i;
  }

  $avg = array_sum($avg_vals) / count($avg_vals);

  return array($x[0], $x[1], $avg);
};

$new = array_map('dan_is_awesome', $arr);
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Ya'll both just saved me loads of time, I coudln't comprehend it for some reason.   Anyway thank you.

Comment: what if the array is is 132 values, and i need value 2,5 and then every 5th after that .. so 7/10 12/15 17/20  and so on up to 132

Comment: @tgr0ss Updated code with example of averaging values as you requested

Comment: Nice function name.  I'd agree at this moment.

Comment: Yeah you see that function name in a lot of serious programming textbooks, so i figured, "When in Rome" ... :)

Comment: Actually I have ot play w/ your code, because the array has 23 keys, with 132 elements in the keys..   What it is is Every generator zone compressed.. need a weighted average to find out out the zone price.   So basically Array (23 keys=> 132 values in each value) .. so would need 2/5/7/10/12/15 .. etc up to 132. to be averaged for each of the 23 keys  .. .  I broke that from 10k lines down to like 2k, and grouped them by hours.  This is my final step before i can dump and put in my real-time table.    These are probalby simple questions, but this is my first php project, 2 months into it.

Comment: I appreciate your help, and I was not asking you to do it for me.  In fact i am still playing with your code.  That was never my intention of they hey be my "bitch" and make this.  A simple point in the right direction, as in Look at these functions or what not would of been fine.   I'm sorry if it came off that way, as those were not my intentions, It's more of a hey, i'm not sure how i should be approaching this- Maybe someone can offer some insite.   .. Once again, Thank you.